# css file not found when hiding url extensions?

Tags: .htaccess

i have figured out a way of hiding url extensions in the users browser that works for my site, 
so www.mysite.com/home.php is now www.mysite.com/home/

the problem i have is the css is now not being pulled/not being found, is there a way i can exclude css, jpg, png gif and js from the .htaccess rewrite?

heres my code im using:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

i have tried adding this but it doesnt work:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !\.css$
```

Comment: from the top of my head adding `RewriteRule css/(.*) css/$1 [NC]` after `RewriteEngine On` might work...

Comment: btw thats a apache mod_rewrite question rather than a php or css one ;)

Comment: thanks for trying but that didnt work :(

Comment: othwerwise is there a way i can change the link to my css path so that it still finds it? my css is stored in assets/css/main.css

Answer (score 0):

try changing

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.php
```

to

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.php
```

Can't be certain though.

Comment: nah, tried that as well, cheers but its not working, still not finding the css, any other ways around this, i've tried directly linking to it i.e: "http://www.mysite.com/assets/css/main.css" but even that won't work